# Multiple navigations with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

I work on a multilingual website (French, English, German). I have built three navigations (with buttons), one for every language. When I open the site the French navigation appears (this works). I can change the navigation with three buttons (in form of flags). This works too. When I press one of the buttons in the navigation the correct page appears. BUT: I then see always all three navigations.

Question: what must I do that after havong pressed a button in a navigation bar this navigation stays alone? I tried it with JavaScript and jQuery but couldn't find a solution.

Any help/hint appreciated very much!

Max

Answer (score 0):

1/ create a class in css

```
.notDisplay {
    display:   none;
}
```

2/ To each button you want to hide, apply the class in javascript using jquery

```
$('#button1').addClass('notDisplay');
```

If you want to show again the button, use

```
$('#button1').removeClass('notDisplay');
```

Do you understand it or have i to explain it more?